# In EmEditor, what expression to use to filter for rows containing mismatching number of specified characters across two columns

Tags: emeditor

If column 1 contains one specified character, e.g., “(“ and column 2 contains two of these characters, which expression to use to filter for these rows. The specified character could be any other character. See attached image as an illustration of the question.[image]

Comment: I am not sure which one is the specified character in this example, especially Line 3 `System Lockdown`. `System Lockdown` appears only once in Column 2. Please clarify your question.

Comment: In this example, the specified character is an opening parenthesis, that is, “(“. Going by the example above, the expression should find rows 2 and 3, since the number of open parentheses do not match between columns 1 and 2 for these rows.

Comment: I see. I was confused because you wrote "The specified character could be any other character". I've answered to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **JavaScript** replacement expressions in the **Replace** dialog of EmEditor.

1. Click the third empty column heading to select the whole third column.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to display the **Replace** dialog box.
3. Click the **Advanced...** button to display the **Advanced** dialog box. Click **Reset** and **OK**. This step ensures the advanced options are set as default.
4. In the **Replace** dialog box, Enter:

- **Find:** `.*`
- **Replace with:** `\J cell(-2).split("(").length != cell(-1).split("(").length ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"`

5. Make sure the **Regular Expressions** and **In the Selection Only** options are set.
6. Click **Replace All**.